# VueJS 2.0 Communicating from the Parent to the Child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

In my html file I have the following button:

```
<button @click="showModal">Show Modal</button>
```

Clicking that button runs the following method:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    methods: {
        showModal() { Event.$emit('showModal'); },
    }
});
```

What I want to happen when I click on that button is to toggle a class in a modal component.  Here is the relevant code for the component:

```
Vue.component('modal', {

    template: `
        <div :class="[ modalClass, {'is-active' : isActive }]">
            ETC...
        </div>
        `

    data() {
        return {
            isActive: false,
            modalClass: 'modal'
        }
    }
```

I am new to VueJS and am trying to figure out how to communicate in Vue.  I can't seem to figure out the next step.  What do I have to do so that isActive is set to true when the button is clicked?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

All the best,

Moshe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main.js (or where ever you instantiate your Vue app)

You can use a plain vue instance as an eventbus

```
Vue.prototype.bus = new Vue();
```

this way you can use it as so :

```
this.bus.$on('event', (params) => {})

this.bus.$emit('event', params)
```

Check out one of my vue project on github as an example, i the eventbus a lot.
 https://github.com/wilomgfx/vue-weather

Also check out this free amazing series on VueJS 2, its really great :
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Full blown example using the op's question:

https://codepen.io/wilomgfx/pen/OpEVpz?editors=1010

Comment: This looks promising, but I"m still having trouble figuring out how to implement it.  What do I add to the modal component so that when I click on the button isActive will be set to true and the modal will show?  I set up a CodePen with my code in case that helps:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpdYgL?editors=0010

Comment: P.S.  Thanks for the Laracasts reference -- I am actually going through that very series right now and agree that it is great.

Comment: Never mind -- I figured it out and it works!  Thanks :).

Comment: Haha alright ! Great glad i could help :)!. You can hit me up anywhere if you need more help, im really active in react and vuejs atm.

Comment: Thanks -- shall do.

Comment: Truth be told, I actually have another question (if you are able).  You can view it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986380/vuejs-2how-to-pass-parameters-using-emit.  Either way, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate from parent to child you can use [components props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

If you have a more deeper communication (parent communicate with little-little...-child) you can use the busEvent mention by @WilomGfx.

Code for communication from parent to child :

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '<div :class="[ modalClass, {\'is-active\' : isActive }]">' +
            'Hello Word !' +
        '</div>',
    data() {
        return {
            modalClass: 'modal'
        }
    },
    props: {
        isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data() {
      return {
        isActive: false,
      }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {this.isActive = true },
  }
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <modal :is-active="isActive"></modal>
  <button @click="showModal">Show Modal (going red when prop isActive is true)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's definitely helpful, but not 100% what I want.  I would like to know is if there is a way to communicate WITHOUT having to add a custom property to the modal tag.  In other words, I would like this `<modal>CONTENT</modal>`.  NOT this:  `<modal :is-active="isActive">CONTENT</modal>

Comment: @Moshe That is a pointless goal that will cause you to write worse code. Props are the correct way for a component to receive external state.

Comment: Ok if eventbus is good for you.
I showed you props because I was thinking about this case :
Imagine you have 3 modals component in your app : you can't use emit because if you use it, all modals will change.