# Pass parameter while emitting using Vuejs event hub

Tags: vue.js

I have checked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986380/vuejs-2-how-to-pass-parameters-using-emit), but there is still one thing that is unclear to me:

Can I pass a parameter in emit on event hub, but I need parameter to be VALUE and not the VARIABLE which stores value. So for example: `eventHub.$emit('test_emit', true)` and the method which is called on `test_emit` should have it's parameter set on true.

Comment: Yes, you can, but what have you tried?

Comment: Exactly that, the method I am trying to call should have it's parameter set on true only when called through event hub and in all other cases it should be false. But I am not sure how to get that parameter, when I pass it as value. 
On the other side I've got `eventHub.$on('test_emit', this.functionINeed)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the similar question that you provided, you would just replace `name` with `true` when you are emitting event

```
methods: {
    showModal(name) { this.bus.$emit('showModal', true); },
}

created() {
    // `show` will have the value that you emitted
    this.bus.$on('showModal', (show) => console.log(show);
}
```

Comment: And that `true` value would be written in `show` variable?

Comment: One more thing, how would look the part with `eventHub.$off`? Do I need to include same variable there or not?

Comment: No, you just specify the event name that you want to disable. [documentation for $off](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off). So `this.bus.$off('showModal')` is enough

Comment: Because you can add multiple listeners for the same event, `this.bus.$off('showModal')` will remove all those listeners for `showModal` event

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, what you cannot do is to pass more then one variable (like `eventHub.$emit('test_emit', true, false)` as $emit accepts only one additional parameter (that can be the value or an object containing the key: value associations, also know as *payload*.

Comment: Okay and how to you get it on the other side, where you have`eventHub.$on`?

Comment: `eventHub.$on('test_emit', theValue => ...);` or if you provide a function, the function first parameter will be the value itself, like: `eventHub.$on('test_emit', anyFn); anyFn = function(value) { console.log(value) }`